# C# Does UpdateFromQuery work with InMemory DB?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-extensions

Does UpdateFromQueryAsync work with Sql InMemory Database? It does need  currently update in my current unit test.

```
 var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<StoreContext>()
       .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "Test")
       Options;

 using (var webStoreContext= new WebStoreContext(options))
 {
      await webStoreContext.Set<Product>().UpdateFromQueryAsync(x => new Product
      {
         ProductType= 'Electronics'
         UpdateDate = DateTime.Now
      }
```

**Resource:**

https://entityframework-extensions.net/update-from-query

Comment: Looks like you've tried it, does it work?

Comment: maybe Im doing something wrong, but no @devNull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,

`UpdateFromQuery` is compatible with `InMemory` database.

If you get an issue, I recommend you to report it here: https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Extensions/issues with a runnable example that show the error.

Comment: its not giving an error, its just Not updating values with inmemory database, but it is working on a Real database in real production, so thats good at least

Comment: It also updates data. As said, if you have a problem, report it in the official Issue Tracker if that's not already done.